# Ошибки в Android Studio Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое values-v24.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
   <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored"/>
   <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media"/>
   <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media"/>
   <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media"/>
   <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media"/>
</resources>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.finderproject"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
}
```

Если кто-нибудь сталкивался, подскажите: как исправить?

Comment: Добавьте содержимое values-v24.xml в вопрос.

Comment: build.gradle тоже прикрепите

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас версия `compileSdkVersion` не совпадает с версией *support library*

То есть если `compileSdkVersion 25`, то версии support библиотеки должна быть что-то типа:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Главное, чтобы *major* версия (здесь 25) совпадала с `compileSdkVersion`